# Delays between "50", "40", "30", "20", and "10" cockpit announcements

Tags: landing, boeing-777, descent, glideslope

When a large airplane is about to land, the following announcements are heard in the cockpit:

"Fifty!"
(delay)
"Forty!"
(delay)
"Thirty!"
(delay)
"Twenty!"
(delay)
"Ten!"

What are the delays' values that would indicate that the plane is descending at a normal rate?

Comment: You understand that these are calling out AGL altitudes right? The delay depends on the descent rate. "Normal" is a matter of aircraft and the situation.

Comment: Quickly plot them out and verify that they are asymptotically approaching zero.  :-)

Comment: That implies an infinitely long runway.

Comment: @RonBeyer, the aircraft is Boeing-777, and "normal" situation is a standard 3 or so degree glideslope. I thought the delays would depend on the angle but not on aircraft.

Comment: It depends on aircraft because even though they use the same 3-ish degree glideslope, the aircraft have different speeds. For an extreme example, I can follow a 3 degree glideslope in a Piper Cub at 50 knots, or a 777 at 150 knots, it's the same path, but those call-outs (if the cub had them) would happen a lot faster on a 777.

Comment: Are you expecting the pilot to have a stopwatch to time the delays to ensure the rate of descent is appropriate instead of relying on the array of instruments already in front of him?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on a lot of things. That’s just a radar altimeter counting down on short final.  By that point almost all of the control of the rate of descent is being done by the pilot vis a vis visual cues to arrive at a particular touchdown area on the runway.  Pilot will increase or decrease their rate of descent accordingly.  Delays or lack there of in that aural warning is irrelevant.  Pilots do however use such audible cues as signals for reducing engine thrust and pitching to the appropriate roundout attitude for touchdown, e.g. the ‘RETARD RETARD’ cue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no value, or set of values that is "correct", but for perspective if the approach were flown at a reasonable 600 feet per minute rate of descent the plane would be descending at 100' every 10 seconds, or 10' every second.  (No aircraft type, airspeed, or glideslope angle calculations are necessary - although they affect rate of descent, the descent rate is the only factor in play for the interval of these calls.)

So, if the pilot did nothing to arrest the rate of descent the 10' increment calls you gave in your example would come every second in a continuous conversational cadence all the way to touchdown.  The goal of a butter soft landing would be for the rate of descent to equal zero just as the wheels touch down, but a "normal" time interval between calls is difficult to quantify because it isn't linear.

I haven't personally flown with an automated altitude alerting system such as the one you describe, nor have I had a copilot making such calls, (heck, a solid majority of my landings have been at 600fpm...) but just like the visual cues a pilot will use to judge height above touchdown to flare, I would imagine that you would quickly get a feel for the sense of timing and appropriate decreasing pace of the interval between calls, and learn to adjust intuitively with some practice.

i.e. Inside of 50 feet if the calls start coming every second the hair on the back of your neck ought to tingle, and you will need to quickly think about starting to apply some back pressure to arrest the descent and prevent a hard landing.